# Passing $_GET variables using form submit action

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, forms

I am trying to pass the table and database variables into a new page via the url so I can dynamically query the specified database and table using `$_GET`. I have tried saving the variables and appending them to the page using `window.onload` with JavaScript but the  `error_log` says  `Undefined index:  db & tbl` which I assume means the variables are not being passed correctly.

I am therefore asking if I can pass these variables using the submit form action instead of using JavaScript ?? Or how can I fix the script to properly pass in the variables?

**My Form**

```
    <form method="post" action="db_search.php">
        Search : <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off"
            value="<?php echo $val;?>"> <input type="submit" name="submit"
            id="submit" value="Search">
    </form>
```

**Script in db_search.php**

```
function pageSet () {
    var yourTbl = window.sessionStorage.getItem("tbl");
    var yourDB = window.sessionStorage.getItem("db");
    window.location.href ='db_search.php?db=' + yourDB + '&tbl=' + yourTbl ;
};
window.onload=pageSet();
```

When `db_search.php` loads, the variables are appended to the url but the page just keeps refreshing.

Comment: change `method="post"` to  `method="get"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could adjust your PHP to use `$_REQUEST` and adjust the form as follows:

```
<form method="post" action="db_search.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="db" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['db'] ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="tbl" value="<?php echo $_REQUEST['tbl'] ?>" />
    Search : <input type="text" name="name" id="name" autocomplete="off"
        value="<?php echo $val;?>"> <input type="submit" name="submit"
        id="submit" value="Search">
</form>
```

This will add the `$_GET` parameters as `$_POST` parameters. Your script will match `$_REQUEST` parameters, thus both `$_POST` and `$_GET` occurances of 'db' will be used. `$_POST` has priority over `$_GET` in `$_REQUEST`.

Making it concrete:

```
//You now match db like:
$db = $_GET['db'];

// Change that to
$db = $_REQUEST['db'];
```

This way no matter if db is sent through GET or POST, it will be filled

Comment: Thank you very much for your response and your examples.

Comment: Your welcome! Good luck with the further development of your project!

Answer (score 0):

try this;

```
<form method="get" action="db_search.php">
```

Comment: This will work but another input (hidden?) would be required for the `tbl`parameter that should also be passed by the looks of the `pageSet` function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the $_POST variable.

Or perhaps you should think about storing those variables server side in a PHP Session.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['tbl'] = $_POST['tbl'];
    $_SESSION['db'] = $_POST['db'];
?>
```

Then get them out agains

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $table = $_SESSION['tbl'];
    $db = $_SESSION['db'];
?>
```